# "Cant Find" message in (vanilla) Js Search

Tags: javascript, css, search

I have the code below. It searches for a **visually hidden div with a value**. **Everything works fine but I need to add an element that shows up when the search finds nothing.** I don't even have the slightest idea how to do it. Thank you in advance for your help.

In case someone needs more code, please write CSS/HTML message.

```
function search() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("search-input");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("search");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
    txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: so document.createElement and appendChild OR have the element on the page which is hidden by default and show it.

Comment: Is there anything you can do to help me with that? I am just learning

Comment: But how do I trigger this element when the search has found nothing?

Comment: basic boolean, set it to true if something is found. Outside the loop, check to see if it is false, if it is you know nothing was found.

Comment: Well, I didn't know how to do this in JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Count the number of results in the for-loop. If amount of results === '0' then display another element showing the text 'no results found'. Here is an example of how that might look like:

```js
function search() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue, resultsCount = 0;
  input = document.getElementById("search-input");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("search");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
    txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
      resultsCount++;
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
  var notFound = document.getElementById('not-found')
  if(resultsCount === 0) {
    notFound.innerHTML = filter + ' not found';
    notFound.style.display = "";
  } else {
    notFound.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search-input" onkeyup="search()" />
<ul id="search">
  <li><div>foo</div></li>
  <li><div>bar</div></li>
  <li><div>baz</div></li>
</ul>

<div id="not-found"></div>
```

Comment: Thx you. Examples are better than 1000 words.